# Tablesorter value should always be visible when choosing a filter

Tags: tablesorter

I am currently using table sorter and just want to know if there is a way to have a value by default always shows up regardless of the selected filter from the filter-select list. I tried using filter functions, but after I added a filter function for a column that has a filter-select, it loses the filter-select list with all of the available values.

For example, here is the filter function that I tried using, it should show "John" regardless of the values that are selected:

```
    0 : function(e, n, f, i, $r, c, data) {
      var x = e===f;
      var y = e==='John';
      var show = x|y;

      return show;
    },
```

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, the `OR` operator requires two vertical bars:

```
0 : function(e, n, f, i, $r, c, data) {
   var x = e===f;
   var y = e==='John';
   var show = x || y;

   return show;
 },
```

Maybe a better method would be to use the [`filter_defaultFilter` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-defaultfilter) which can be used as follows ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/1085/)):

```
$(function() {
  $('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
    widgetOptions: {
      filter_defaultFilter: {
        // Ox will always show
        // {q} is replaced by the user query
        2: '{q}|Ox'
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Also, make sure to include a "filter-match" class name in the header cell:

```
<th class="filter-match">...</th>
```

otherwise "OR" queries default to exact cell content matches.