# Tablesorter: don't show specific column values as filters

Tags: tablesorter

Is there a way to remove a column value as a filter on a column that has a "filter-select" attribute.

Here's an example from @mottie in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/1085/. I just added a "filter-select" on column **Animal** column. is there a way for example to remove **Koala** from the drop down filter values?

**HTML**

```
<table class="tablesorter">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>AlphaNumeric</th>
        <th>Numeric</th>
        <th class="filter-match filter-select">Animals</th>
        <th>Sites</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 123</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Koala</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 1</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Ox</td>
        <td>http://www.yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Girafee</td>
        <td>http://www.facebook.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>zyx 24</td>
        <td>767</td>
        <td>Bison</td>
        <td>http://www.whitehouse.gov/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 11</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Chimp</td>
        <td>http://www.ucla.edu/</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Script: Tablesorter**

```
    /* Documentation for this tablesorter FORK can be found at
* http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/
*/
// See http://stackoverflow.com/q/40899404/145346
$(function(){
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_defaultFilter: {
        // Ox will always show
        2: '{q}|Ox'
      }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you will need the [`filter_selectSource` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-selectsource) to manipulate the options of the select ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/1088/))

```
$(function() {
  $('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
    widgetOptions: {
      filter_defaultFilter: {
        // Ox will always show
        2: '{q}|Ox'
      },
      filter_selectSource: function(table, column, onlyAvail) {
        // get an array of all table cell contents for a table column
        var array = $.tablesorter.filter.getOptions(table, column, onlyAvail);
        // remove Koala (multiple entries) from array
        return $.grep(array, function(animal) {
          return animal !== "Koala";
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```